# How to take the last non-blank value in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a rather interesting question.

I have a simple table that calculates each day 2 values (value 1 + value 2) and it gives me a total ( sum(val1+val2) ).
In a different cell, I wish to take the last populated total value, so if I we take the image as a reference it would be 19.

So, if Wednesdays Total value cell has a value, I want the 'Last Total Value' cell to contain that value. But if Thursdays Total value cell has been populated, then I want the 'Last Total Value' cell to update itself automatically to the Thursdays Total value.
Here's an image of the table:

[image]

How can I achieve this in google sheets?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F:F,F:F),-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :)

```
=INDEX(C:C,MAX(IF(C:C<>"",ROW(C:C),0)))
```

This formula uses the INDEX function along with the MAX and IF functions to find the last non-blank cell in column C. It searches for the maximum row number where a value exists in column C and returns the corresponding value.

Now, when you populate a value in a cell in the "Total Value" column for a particular day, the "Last Total Value" cell will automatically update to display the last populated total value.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a bunch of different ways to do the filtering for blanks with various levels of verbosity and two different ways to obtain the last row. Obviously, @ztiaa's answer, the top value, is the most concise. Though it is only possible if there are no other values in that column.

Filtering for blanks is easy, by default they are excluded, but there are a number of ways of making that explicit for other users of your spreadsheet, like `ISNUMBER, NOT(ISBLANK()) and <>""`.

You can get the last row by using reverse indexing and `CHOOSEROWS(list, -1)`, or you can get the Max Row number of the filtered list `MAX(ROW(FILTER(list))))`

|  | function |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F:F,F:F),-1)` |
| 2 | `=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F4:F10,F4:F10),-1)` |
| 3 | `=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F4:F10,F4:F10<>""),-1)` |
| 4 | `=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F4:F10,ISNUMBER(F4:F10)),-1)` |
| 5 | `=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F4:F10,NOT(ISBLANK(F4:F10))),-1)` |
| 6 | `=CHOOSEROWS(F4:F10,MAX(ROWS(FILTER(F4:F10,F4:F10))))` |
| 7 | `=INDEX(F4:F10,MAX(ROWS(FILTER(F4:F10,F4:F10))))` |